# Arteries used for inserting catheter

Tags: human-anatomy, hematology, circulatory-system

For catheter purpose, femoral and subclavian arteries are mostly used as starting point. Why? Are there other arteries which are used for the purpose?

Comment: What research have you done? What aspect you didn't understand?

Comment: research - "For catheter purpose, femoral and subclavian arteries are mostly used as starting point."

Comment: What have you searched regarding your question?

Comment: depends on the purpose that you're talking about... we insert catheters for hemodynamic monitoring into the radial, brachial, femoral arteries. For other percutaneous methods, other arteries could be accessed, but less commonly - depends on what purposes your talking about

Answer (score 2):

Those arteries are (a) big enough for the catheters, (b) superficial enough (close enough to the surface of the skin) for catheterization. It would be quite a challenge to use the renal arteries, for a ridiculous example. There is also less of a risk of embolization than using an artery like the carotid, where embolism can cause stroke, which would be quite serious. An embolism in an arm or leg could be painful and cause damage, but unless it is massive it isn't going to significantly affect the patient over the long term.

Also note that those are fairly special cases of catheterization, such as when doing percutaneous interventional techniques targeting the peripheral or coronary arteries. Those approaches use fairly large devices so you need a large vessel, and you need to be in the portion of the vasculature that you are targeting (i.e., you can't access those targets through a vein). As @VanceLAlbaugh mentioned in a comment, other arteries are targeted for other purposes. And overall venous catheterization is much more common than arterial, such as when an IV line is established to deliver fluids/medicines.